# Images vertically stretched in Safari with parent container as display flex

Tags: css, safari

I have a simple ul/li with images/text inside it. In Safari the images are getting vertically stretched:

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
        <a><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg/1024px-Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg.png">SharePoint</a></li>
                    <li>
        <a><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg/1024px-Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg.png">SharePoint</a></li>
                    <li>
        <a><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg/1024px-Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg.png">SharePoint</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    border-top: 0 solid #efefef;
    color: inherit;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 30px 12px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

 ul.dropdown-menu li a img {
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Safari:

[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Live fiddle URL to test:
https://jsfiddle.net/raghav_khunger/ko0wybhx/8/

I can add hardcoded height 25px to the image to overcome this issue:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li a img
```

One more solution could be having align-items: center; rule to .dropdown-menu > li > a (https://jsfiddle.net/raghav_khunger/ko0wybhx/10/)

Is there any other solution to it?

Are the above solutions valid for making the images do not stretch?

Can you share the reason why the images are getting stretched in the Safari whereas it is working fine in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this code, hope it will work for you.

```css
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    border-top: 0 solid #efefef;
    color: inherit;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 30px 12px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    
}

 ul.dropdown-menu li a img {
    width: 25px;
   
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
            <a>
              <div>
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg/1024px-Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg.png">SharePoint
              </div>
            </a></li>
                         <li>
            <a>
              <div>
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg/1024px-Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg.png">SharePoint
              </div>
            </a></li>
             <li>
            <a>
              <div>
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg/1024px-Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_%282018%E2%80%93present%29.svg.png">SharePoint
              </div>
            </a></li>
            </ul>
```